# Send request to graphQL api site WikiCSMoney over HTTP and get JSON Response in Java

Tags: java, http, graphql, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to make a request to a service WikiCsMoney and get a response in json format. I made the following request

```
String uri = "https://wiki.cs.money/graphql?query=query%20skin($id:%20ID!)%20{%20%20skin(id:%20$id)%20{%20%20%20%20price_trader_log%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20%20%20values%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20price_trader_new%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20}%20%20}}&operationName=skin&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22usp-s-torque%22%7D"
```

If I take and manually through the command line of the browser or through the Postman execute this request, then it returns the answer I need.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FY8g.png)

I am making a request in an appropriate manner

```
public  String sendRequestToWiki(String PROXY_HOST) throws IOException {
        String uri = "https://wiki.cs.money/graphql?query=query%20skin($id:%20ID!)%20{%20%20skin(id:%20$id)%20{%20%20%20%20price_trader_log%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20%20%20values%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20price_trader_new%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20}%20%20}}&operationName=skin&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22usp-s-torque%22%7D";
        //String encodedURI = URLEncoder.encode(uri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        System.out.println(uri);
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod method = new PostMethod(uri);

        HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
        config.setProxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);

        client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);
        client.executeMethod(method);

        String responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        JSONObject skinInfo = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONObject itemInf = skinInfo.getJSONObject("skin");
        JSONArray priceTraderLog = itemInf.getJSONArray("price_trader_log");
        String nameItem = priceTraderLog.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
        return nameItem;
}
```

But i get following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'https://wiki.cs.money/graphql?query=query%20skin($id:%20ID!)%20{%20%20skin(id:%20$id)%20{%20%20%20%20price_trader_log%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20%20%20values%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20price_trader_new%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20}%20%20}}&operationName=skin&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22usp-s-torque%22%7D': Invalid query
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:222)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.<init>(GetMethod.java:89)
    at noSteam.SteamPage.sendRequestToWiki(SteamPage.java:526)
    at noSteam.MainTester.main(MainTester.java:25)
```

Can someone help me solve this problem, because if you manually send a request, then we get the right answer, which means that Yuri is correct, maybe I'm using the wrong approach to executing the request. thanks in advance!

Comment: query in url = GET method (usually not supported, but if tested/works it can be OK) ... but those params (included in uri: query, variables) probably should be removed from uri and defined/passed some other way (failed client/lib uri validation requirements/assertions ... but sorry ... IDK how, IDK java)

Comment: i think i solve problem , the problem with encoding url, i fix that , so now uri look like that String uri = "https://wiki.cs.money/graphql?query=query%20skin($id:%20ID!)%20%7b%20%20skin(id:%20$id)%20%7b%20%20%20%20price_trader_log%20%7b%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20%20%20values%20%7b%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20price_trader_new%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%20%20%20%20%20%20%7d%20%20%20%20%7d%20%20%7d%7d&operationName=skin&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22"+ skinNameForWiki + "%22%7D";